# Onedrive for business : silent authentication

Tags: php, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, onedrive

I need to let many users upload powerpoint presentations and have my webapp request the embed link for it, so it can be shown in an iframe.

The powerpoint presentations all need to be stored in one place so they're safe. Not in users  own live accounts that is. So I wanted to use our corporate live account (which is not onedrive business).

Does anyone have any idea how to do this? I think OneDrive business (office 365) is too expensive for what we're using it for, and it seems like the OneDrive SDK docs are much clearer and they offer the possibility to return an embed link which if I'm not mistaken is not possible through the SharePoint API..

Comment: You mean to allow 'many' users in a organization build/share presentations where you have authority over auditing/controlling the content's distribution and organization?

Comment: Exactly. I need users to be able to upload a powerpoint presentation so it can be shown on the webapplication. Apparently OneDrive is the only way you can keep the ppt animations, so I need to use it. I just want all the ppt's to be stored in a space that we as a company have control over so users can't screw things up. That's why I wanted to authenticate silently using our company's onedrive account. Which is not an office 365 account.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud services such as OneDrive are built to operate from the calling users context, which could have access to shared content over in another account. For good or bad, if you want to manage these shared content systems you need to control your 'authorized' user pools.  For smaller scale operations this does not block work, but becomes manual tax that the developer of the app takes on.

If you have a large number of users or have strict requirements about users entering/exiting the organization then you'll want to look into using your active directory base with O356 as its designed from the ground up for this, there is a API there is a [new preview api from those folks for interacting with files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605892(v=office.15).aspx).  It sounds like this might not meet your cost requirements, but this would definitely be the best tool designed for that job.

If you wanted to use the public OneDrive offering and do some manual group management you can look into the [LiveSDK](https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK) which are available to all consumer OneDrive accounts, however the experience will require a lot more footwork, and I'm not sure the full extend of your scenario that you'll be able to implement, but this should meet your cost management/requirements.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I went along and have users upload their files to their OneDrive account in a folder that I create through the API and request the embed link and save that to the database. As a fallback, I went ahead and upload the powerpoints to crocodoc, which also works but without the animations. Just in case users accidently delete their onedrive files or account.

Comment: Great to hear that you linked it up in a functional way.  You could always save a copy of the presentations to your own 'backup' account on OneDrive if you wanted to keep things 'in service'.